# Interpreting Python open function segment

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python applied to Machine Learning from this [book](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/building-machine-learning-systems-python).
I ran into the following code from chapter 3 which I don't fully understand:

```
posts = [open(os.path.join(DIR, f)).read() for f in
os.listdir(DIR)]
```

I have an idea of what the open function does but I get confused when I see the os.path.join function and for f. Can I get an intuitive and detailed answer that a noob programmer can understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a list comprehension. It's equivalent to the following:

```
posts = []
for f in os.listdir(DIR):
    filename = os.path.join(DIR, f)
    file = open(filename)
    content = file.read()
    posts.append(content)
```

For each filename in a directory listing, this will combine the filename with the full path, open it, read it, and add it to the `posts` list.